# d3.js: How to deal with svg elements that are being appended on the same position, one on top of the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 map (using albers projection) in an svg element, to which I am appending circles based on the latitude and longitude of each data point I have. However, some of the data points appear at the same latitude and longitude, and so the elements (in this case circles) are being appended one on top of the other.

I would like to either offset the circles slightly based on whether a circle already exists at the same lat/long projection, or append another element like a rectangle that demonstrates how many data points lie at that particular projection.

However, I can't figure out quite how I would do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a clean, easy way to say: If there is already a  element in this location, do something?

Comment: Along with the transparency solution offered by @Lars below, you might consider randomizing your data within the bounds of accuracy. For example, if your data is only accurate to within locations of +/- `0.5`, you could randomize the items by +/- `0.4` so that they would not stack on top of each other exactly.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz -- that's a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no easy way to do this -- in general, you would have to iterate over the existing elements, checking whether any of them is in the same position as the current element. You do however have a few other options.

#### Preprocess the data

Before drawing, iterate over your data and merge elements at the same position. You could add another attribute to the merged data that tells you to use another symbol, draw bigger circles or something like that.

#### Use transparency

The alternative would be to make the circles semi-transparent. This way, several circles at the same position would give less overall transparency, showing that there is more data at that position.

The latter solution would be the easiest to implement, as it only requires setting an attribute.

Comment: Thanks Lars! Will try that out! Both sound like great ideas.